# Copy file on SFTP to another directory without roundtrip

Tags: sftp

I tried this, but of course it doesn't work:

```
sftp> cp baz.txt foo/bar/
Invalid command.
```

Is there a way to do that with an `sftp` connection?

---

Of course, I realize that this is trivial if I connect with `ssh` instead. However, I have an sftp server where I can't actually do that, since `ssh`-ing gives me a different start directory, and I have no power over (or even knowledge of) the absolute paths on the remote; I need everything to work relative to the startup directory when I connect with `sftp`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A core SFTP protocol does not support duplicating a remote file.

There's draft of the [`copy-file` extension to the protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-extensions-00), but that's supported by only few SFTP servers ([ProFTPD `mod_sftp`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html) and Bitvise SFTP server for example) and few SFTP clients ([WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_move_duplicate) for example).

The most widespread SFTP server, the OpenSSH supports related `copy-data` only in very recent [version 9.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0). Its `sftp` client has now [`cp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#cp)/[`copy`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#copy) command.

---

Alternatives (which you seem to know and won't help you):

- If you have SSH/terminal access into the server, use the [shell `cp` command](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html).
- If your SFTP server supports the `copy-file` extension, use an SFTP client that supports it too.
- Otherwise, your only option is to download the file to a local temporary location and upload its copy back to a different/target remote directory.
  Some SFTP clients can do this for you even transparently in one go (e.g. in WinSCP, see *Duplicate via local temporary copy* option on [Duplicate dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_duplicate)).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Since the remote is hosted by an external company, and we have no say in what software they use, I can't rely on anything except the standard protocol. The files are quite small, so I'll live with the inelegance of downloading and uploading again.

Answer (score 0):

`sftp` protocol does not have any commands to copy files on remote server. See [manual page for `sftp`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sftp&sektion=1) to list of available commands.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, i do this all the time with the scp command via terminal in mac.

scp [options] username1@source_host:directory1/filename1 username2@destination_host:directory2/filename2

Comment: That's SCP, not SFTP. In many cases, if you have SFTP access, SCP will work too. But not always.

Comment: Using `scp` will place the OP in the same directory as `ssh`. The discrepancy between directories for `ssh` and `sftp` is the core of the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the FTP commands like

```
sftp> put baz.txt /foo/bar/baz.txt
```

Comment: this is not what the OP wants. This copies from local to remote, but the question is about remote to remote, if I got that right.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: You're right, I missed something